# Getting Cannot access memory at address error

Tags: c++, gdb

I get this error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400f8b in encryptFile (
inPath=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff63a0f8>, 
outPath=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff63a0f0>, 
key=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff63a0e8>) at    main3.cpp:7
7   bool encryptFile(std::string& inPath, std::string& outPath, unsigned char * key) {
```

This is the code:

```c
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define buffersize 10240000

bool encryptFile(std::string& inPath, std::string& outPath, unsigned char * key)
{
  unsigned char mbuf[buffersize];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned char k[32];
  std::string clear = "clear.bin";
  std::string crypt = "crypt.bin";
  encryptFile(clear, crypt, &k[0]);
}
```

the strange thing is however, if I set

```
#define buffersize 10240
```

everything works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: running out of stack space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On most modern systems *automatic variables* will be placed on the *stack* and so you are overflowing your limited stack space. Typical stack sizes are somewhere between `1M to 8M` and `mbuf` is about `10M` with a size of `10240000`. A better option would be to use dynamic memory allocation or even better since this is *C++* you can just use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and not have to worry about *deleting* dynamically allocated memory when you are done. [Stack Overflow Problems](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/doc/stackOverflow.txt) covers the typical stack sizes on common systems:

```
SunOS/Solaris   8172K bytes
Linux           8172K bytes
Windows         1024K bytes
cygwin          2048K bytes
```